# Ajax request not working for controller action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, controller

I am trying to generate an ajax request to call the blog controller count action but I am getting an error and I am not able to figure out the reason. Please help me find it. Below is the code with the error.

blogs_controller.rb

```
  def count
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @blog.increment!(:blog_count)
    redirect_back(fallback_location: blogs_path)
  end
```

show.html.erb

```
<button onclick="CountFun()" class="btn btn-success float-right" id="first" >Copy</button>

<script>
 $('#first').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "#{blog_count_path(@blog)}"
  });
 });
</script>
```

Error message

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: blog):

app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:79:in `blog_params'
app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:45:in`block in update'
app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:44:in `update'

Just for test whether I had defined the controller action in the correct way I had this add this link_to button just to see if it works and it works like a champ it just that the I am getting an error with the ajax request.

```
<%= link_to 'Count', blog_count_path(@blog), method: :put, id: 'second' %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :blogs, path: '/' do
 put :count
end
```

Comment: Did you check for the PUT request to be sent to the right URL? Have you tried adding a data: { blog_id: WHATEVER } to the request and see if that works?

Comment: try `#{blog_count_path(:blog_id => @blog.id)` or add `data: {blog_id : #{@blog.id}`

Comment: You're claiming about `count` action but error is in the `update` action.

Comment: @NickM I tried it with blog_id: 2 but I got this error **PUT http://localhost:3000/2 400 (Bad Request)**

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan I tried it but got this error PUT http://localhost:3000/2 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan yes I did. I ll update my question with the routes.rb file.

Comment: `$('#first').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "blogs/count",
    data : {blog_id: #{@blog.id}
  });
 });` and in your routes.rb change to `get 'count'`

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan I got this ** Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=blogs):  
app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:66:in `count' **

Comment: can you print the params[:blog_id] in action and check in your terminal whats printing???

Comment: I used the buybug to check the value it does print the value of the id of the blog (byebug) params[:blog_id]
"2"

Comment: are u getting the @blog from Blog.find(params[:blog_id]) ??? try printing that tooo....

Comment: Blog.find(params[:blog_id]) it give me the entire blog record. Blog id: 2, title: "My Blog Post", preview_text: "demo test", body: "body of blog", user_id: 1, created_at: "2019-07-12 09:16:33", updated_at: "2019-07-12 09:16:33", blog_count: 43>

Comment: `@blog.increment!(:blog_count)` did change something to the record?

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan the link_to button which is added as shown in the question works as I want count controller action to work but it doesn't work with ajax request.

Comment: `render json: { flag: true }`add instead of redirect_to

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan PUT http://localhost:3000/2 400 (Bad Request) ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: blog) still the same error

Comment: is your routes.rb still put??

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan yes it is still put.

Comment: change to get 'count'

Comment: I changed it to get, it didn't through up any error but the value is not incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in a different place than you think, the path and the action is corrrect, but your script does not have the right path, because you did just pass it `#{blog_count_path(@blog)}`. `erb` does not see anything to parse there.

So your in your `show.html.erb` you need to make sure you `erb` knows you want to replace something:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: "<%= blog_count_path(@blog) %>"
});
```

A better way would to forget about the script entirely and direct create a button with `remote: true`

```
<%= button_to "Count", blog_count_path(@blog), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a post or put route. You don't have a view to render so just do this in your controller action.

```
def count
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
  if @blog && @blog.increment!(:blog_count)
    render json: { data: 'OK', status: 200 }
  else
    render json: { error: "blog did not increment" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: blog):         I got this error

Comment: @Navroop can you put a buy bug in and find paste the output of params?